# How to get the controller name and the current_user name in model -----ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

> How to get the controller name and the current_user name in model
>     and i want to get these info to save in operation_logs table

now I write these code:

```
module RecordOperation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    after_update :record_operation
    before_destroy :record_operation
    after_create :record_operation
    def record_operation

    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

to get a user name in shell just try using `ENV`:

```
 ENV[ 'USER' ] # => 'username'
```

to get controller name try using:

```
 self.class.to_s.underscore # => 'application_controller'
```